# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Tags: gensim, word2vec, python-3.7

I am trying to extract Indonesia titles from a wiki titles dump that's in a text file using word2vec-gensim in Python 3. The wiki dump contains titles in other languages also and some symbols. Below is my code:

```
    if len(sys.argv) != 3: 
    namaFileInput = "idwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
    namaFileOutput = "wiki.id.case.text"
    sys.exit(1)
inp, outp = sys.argv[1:3]
space = " "
i = 0

output = open(namaFileOutput, 'w')

# lower=False: huruf kecil dan besar dibedakan
wiki = WikiCorpus(namaFileInput, lemmatize=False, dictionary={}, lower=False)
for text in wiki.get_texts():
    if six.PY3:
        output.write(b' '.join(text).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
    else:
        output.write(space.join(text) + "\n")
    i = i + 1
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        logger.info("Saved " + str(i) + " articles")

output.close()
logger.info("Finished Saved " + str(i) + " articles")
```

But I am getting and error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d4c686a9093a> in <module>
     29 for text in wiki.get_texts():
     30     if six.PY3:
---> 31         output.write(b' '.join(text).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
     32     else:
     33         output.write(space.join(text) + "\n")

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

I have searched online but could not succeed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in this line of code: `b' '.join(text)`

The variable `text` is a list of strings but you are trying to join them with a byte-string (namely `b' '`), which doesn't work. You can solve this problem by simply removing `b` since you are converting the string to bytes afterwards anyway with the `.encode('utf-8')` method:

```
output.write(' '.join(text).encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```